# How can I loop over URLs in an excel file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an excel file with over 380 URLs for PDFs.

I want to create a list and then loop over each URL in it, in order to download these PDFs individually.

I keep getting the following error InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'URL

Here's my code below

```
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import requests

mkt_Summ = pd.read_excel(r'Z:\Bloomberg\Khouly\Philippines\Weekly Market Summary URLs.xlsx')

mkt_Summ.values.tolist()

for URL in mkt_Summ:
  requests.get(mkt_Summ)
```

Any help?

Comment: You probably meant to write `requests.get(URL)`

Comment: You get the values as a list but you are never assigning it anywhere. 
That list is what you need to iterate over. 
Essentially, as it is the 6th instruction is without any effect. 
Probably you want to write for URL in mkt_Summ.values.tolist():
  requests.get(URL)